# Getting UTF-8 encoded RSS Feed into PHP - garbage characters

Tags: php, rss

I'm attempting to pull in an RSS feed from another website and display it on my own.

I'm using a library called rsslib.php, here is the relevant function

```
function RSS_Retrieve($url){
global $RSS_Content;

$doc  = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($url);

$channels = $doc->getElementsByTagName("channel");
$RSS_Content = array();
...
```

The RSS feed itself has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the top

And the page I'm displaying this on also has the meta content type set to `UTF-8`

Yet, I'm getting the following coming through in the content....

**Â€™ in place of apostrophes**

Comment: I can confirm the header of rss feed is sending: `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8` and it validates through w3c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `htmlentities`, like this:

```
$text = trim(htmlentities($child->wholeText, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
```

Where `$child` is an instance of `DOMText`.

Also works with other `DOMNode` properties as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks, had to do a bit of replacing on certains bits but that got me there.